# change specific text in text file with scanner class (java)

Tags: java, file, text

I write this code that can search for the some specific text (such as word) in the text file with scanner class, but i want also to replace (old text to the new text) in the same old text locuation.
i find in the internet that i must used replaceAll method like  ( replaceAll(old, new); )
but it does't work with the scanner class.

This is my code, it just search (if it existed ) write new text in new line without change the old one.

Do i need to change the method (to get the data) form scanner to FileReader ??

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users....file.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the content you want to change:");
String Uinput = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("You want to change it to:");
String Uinput2 = input.nextLine();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",");
BufferedWriter writer  = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String lineFromFile = scanner.next();
    if (lineFromFile.contains(Uinput)) {
        lineFromFile = Uinput2;
        writer.write(lineFromFile); 
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("changed " + Uinput + " tO " + Uinput2);
        break;
    }
    else if (!lineFromFile.contains(Uinput)){
        System.out.println("Don't found " + Uinput);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Get all of the file's content(Read from file) and store it in a data structure. 2 Alter content. 3 Save altered content to file(Write to file).

Comment: What do you mean with data structure? how i create this structure

Comment: `String` or `List<String>`. In this case I am leaning toward `List<String>`.

Comment: do i need to change whole my code? or is there better way with using FileReader & FileWriter?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read from a file, then write to that same file. You need 2 different files.

```
  while (read line from input file) { 
      if (NOT matches your search pattern)
            write line to output file.
      else  { // matches
          write start of line to your search pattern.
          write your replace string
          write from end of search pattern to end of line.
      }
   }
```

Unless your replace string is the same size as your search string, yes, you'll have to use 2 files. Consider the file:

```
 Blah
 Blah
 Blah
```

Now replace the letter 'a' with "The quick Brown Fox". If you replace the first line, you've overwritten the rest of the file. Now you can't read the 2nd line, so YES, you'll have to use 2 files.

Comment: i don't understand, are you mean that i need to change all my code? and how i make 2 file if i want to change the same file?

Comment: technically you can read and write to the same file just fine, but it is not trivial to do so. It might work in the case of filtering lines - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer If you use seek(), yes, but the search and replace has to be the same size. Otherwise there's a gap.

Comment: You could use two file pointers - one for reading, the other for writing. But yes, I misread the code. This only works if the replacement is shorter than the line being replaced.

Comment: You can work round the two files limitation by writing the output to a temporary file, then when the processing is finished, and both files are closed, delete the original file and rename the temporary file to the name of the original file.  Best to keep a backup of the original file, just in case.

Comment: @rossum That's still multiple files.

Comment: @khaledgg7 It's not much code. I've written the pseudo code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer based on @Sedrick comment and your code.
I'm adding it to your pseudo code.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users....file.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the content you want to change:");
String Uinput = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("You want to change it to:");
String Uinput2 = input.nextLine();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",");
java.util.List<String> tempStorage = new ArrayList<>();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String lineFromFile = scanner.next();
    tempStorage.add(lineFromFile);
}

 // close input file here
// Open your write file here (same file = overwrite).

// now loop through temp storage searching for input string.
for (String currentLine : tempStorage ) {
     if (!lcurrentLine.contains(Uinput)){
        String temp = currentLine.replace(Uinput, Uinput2);
         write a line using temp variable  
     } else { // not replaced
         write a line using currentLine;  
 }
 // close write file here
```

By the way, you'll have to encase the reads writes with try catch to trap for IOExceptions. That's how I knew it was pseudo code. There are plenty of examples for reading/writing a file on this web site. It's easy to search for.

Comment: thanks for the help, but there are some line in this code i don't understand it. what you mean with  "// Open your write file here (same file = overwrite). what you mean by that?
"  i understand now that i need a temp storage string before I change the old string, but if i run your the code, it say there is a problem with this line         if (!lcurrentLine.contains(Uinput)){    " lcurrentLine cannot be resolved
 Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody "

Comment: thanks it's works now, i change the if (!lcurrentLine >> !currentLine and i remove true from (new FileWriter(file)); thank you for helping me.

Comment: i found another problem the code now works fine if the input exist and change it , but when not it clean all the data in the file!! i think the problem form the "true" part or the IOExceptions

Comment: i found also another problem, if my data in the file like 10 20 30  0, and i put change 0 to 1 , it will change all the zero in the data, so it will be like this 11 21 31 1 , i think my code is not good at all :(

Comment: i fixed the problem with "clean all the data in the file if the input not exist ,but the problem with changing the letter in the word or change not only the 0 in the data (0 10 20 30) but change all 0 like this 1 11 21 31 , the problem with replace method i think